# a good book on relations in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, relations

I am self-studying discrete mathematics and I have troubles in solving the exercises that are included at the end of the chapter in my book. The book that I'm reading is already a good one, but it includes only a few examples and also, it lacks a "Solution to the selected exercises" appendix. The exercises at the end of the chapters are so difficult and unfamiliar to me that I'm only able to solve a few of them. I need a book on the topic of relations and functions, with lots of examples solved, or at least, a book that have the solution to some of the exercises as an appendix. Could you please suggest a book? It does not matter if it is not completely dedicated to the subject. The book I am reading now include topics such as graph and matrix of relations, properties of relations, equivalence relations, operations on relations, combining relations, closures (symmetric, transitive, reflexive), and the like.

Comment: It might improve your Question if you would specifically cite the book whose exercises are giving you difficulty.  A great deal of mathematics falls under the category of discrete mathematics, so focusing on some specific topics (the "topic of relations and functions" is extremely broad) is more likely to lead to helpful replies (for yourself and for future Readers).

Comment: @hardmath, It is "Discrete Mathematics", by B. Gholizadeh, published by Sharif University Publications, only in Iran. It is a book in my local language, this is why I didn't mention the book at the first place, but it includes topics such as graph and matrix of relations, properties of relations, equivalence relations, , operations on relations, combining relations, closures (symmetric, transitive, reflexive), and the like.

Comment: You'll be the expert on what is helpful, but there is an open source text **Discrete Mathematics: An Open Introduction** by Oscar Levin, freely downloadable [here](http://discretetext.oscarlevin.com/home.php).  It seems to have a number of worked or hinted problems, as well as a fewer number of extended exercises without solutions.

Comment: @hardmath, Thank you, I just read the first chapter and it  was helpful, I hope I find more helpful things in the remaining chapters. Thanks again.